# Azure Diagnositcs not storing data, even with default application

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to store the azure diagnostics data on the storage account.
I have tried the following code:

```
public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // For information on handling configuration changes
        // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.
        // Get the default initial configuration for DiagnosticMonitor.
        DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticConfiguration = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

        // Filter the logs so that only error-level logs are transferred to persistent storage.
        diagnosticConfiguration.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Information;

        // Schedule a transfer period of 30 minutes.
        diagnosticConfiguration.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);

        // Specify a buffer quota of 1GB.
        diagnosticConfiguration.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = 900;

        // Start the DiagnosticMonitor using the diagnosticConfig and our connection string.
        DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", diagnosticConfiguration);

        Trace.TraceInformation("WebRole started");

        return base.OnStart();
    }
```

This code is same as microsoft has suggested on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.diagnostics.diagnosticmonitorconfiguration.logs

I have tried to comment out BufferQuotaInMB with no luck. I have tried this with newly created application both in local environment and on live deployment. Turns out that even WADLogsTable is not created.
What is it that i am missing?

Note: it is working alright on live deployment with windowsEventLogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is wrong, as an alternative you could try using the Diagnostics.wadcfg as a config option in your code?

Few blog posts explaining how to use it:

How to use Diagnostics.wadcfg to configure Windows Azure diagnostics collection: http://www.davidaiken.com/2012/02/27/how-to-use-diagnostics-wadcfg-to-configure-windows-azure-diagnostics-collection/

Configuring WAD via the diagnostics.wadcfg Config File: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2011/03/29/configuring-wad-via-the-diagnostics-wadcfg-config-file.aspx

How to Use the Windows Azure Diagnostics Configuration File: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411551.aspx

Worth a try, sorry I couldn't be of more help...

Comment: Not exactly i was looking for, but it works for event logs now.

Answer (score 0):

WadLogTable is not created because our problem is that you haven't used SetCurrentConfiguration() with your GetDefaultInitialConfiguration() to finally save the transfer time and log level. You must use the set of these API as below:

```
GetDefaultInitialConfiguration() 
SetCurrentConfiguration()
```

OR

```
GetCurrentConfiguration()
SetCurrentConfiguration()
```

More Info: [Azure diagnostics and WadLogsTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870665/azure-diagnostics-and-wadlogstable/10871834#10871834)