# Azure logging in the 1.7 SDK

Tags: logging, azure

After upgrading my azure project to the SDK version 1.7, the logs has stopped being transfer to storage. I have been looking at this for a few hours, and can't see what has changed (a diff isn't helping either).

I think I need a set of fresh eyes to help location the problem. Do you see anything wrong here? Did the setup change in the 1.7SDK?

**Web.config**

```
  <system.diagnostics xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

**Service Definition**

```
<Imports>
  <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
</Imports>
```

**CloudConfig**

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString"
               value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[account];AccountKey=[key]" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

**OnStart**

```
var config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

//event log
config.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("System!*");
config.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");
config.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
config.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Warning;


config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Information;
DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", config);

return base.OnStart();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is with your web.config, you need to update the assembly version to 1.7.0.0:

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=**1.7.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Comment: Thanks, I knew I had to be missing something obvious

Comment: Good to keep in mind that if you have a WCF Service in your deployment you should change the WAIISHost.exe.config as well. This config will not be upgraded if you upgrade your deployment!

Comment: Many thanks. I had this problem too and it was driving me insane. I'd never have figured it out on my own. If I could upvote you multiple times, I would!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to follow @Sandrino suggestion also I see some code issue as well. You haven't used SetCurrentConfiguration() with your GetDefaultInitialConfiguration() to finally save the transfer time and log level. You must use the set of these API as below:

```
GetDefaultInitialConfiguration() 
SetCurrentConfiguration()
```

OR

```
GetCurrentConfiguration()
SetCurrentConfiguration()
```

This could cause [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870665/azure-diagnostics-and-wadlogstable) if you start collecting trace messages in your application so its better to have this code complete..

Comment: Isn't my `DiagnosticMonitor.Start("...", config);`  taking and setting it? It seems to be working as is now.